# In which file compiling asp.net web forms controls

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I make some change in one of the control files in my web application. So i donnt want to publish all application but just a few files. Which file i need to replace at my server version? controls\control.ascx doesnt contain necesseary information(it just a few lines). So what is place of builded controls in asp.net web forms?

Comment: Depends on whether you have a "Web Application" or "Web Site" type of project. "Web Application" compiles as a DLL into the "bin" folder. "Web Site" is dynamically compiled, just publish your "controls\control.ascx.cs", too.

Comment: @Uwe Keim Assume i have two sites and two project types.